# Python3 Textblob detection - ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, textblob

I am using textblob detecct_language, which worked two weeks ago. Just basic usage.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
text = "C  ®:     -  "
lang = TextBlob(text).detect_language()
```

Now it raises ValueError.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-bad6e63440b4> in <module>
      3 text = "C  ®:     -  "
      4 lang = TextBlob(text)
----> 5 lang.detect_language()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py in detect_language(self)
    566         :rtype: str
    567         """
--> 568         return self.translator.detect(self.raw)
    569 
    570     def correct(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py in detect(self, source, host, type_)
     71         url = u'{url}&sl=auto&tk={tk}'.format(url=self.url, tk=_calculate_tk(source))
     72         response = self._request(url, host=host, type_=type_, data=data)
---> 73         result, language = json.loads(response)
     74         return language
     75 

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Totally have no idea what's causing the error.

Comment: I encountered this error too. The lang detection uses a Google API so my guess is that something changed with the Google API. Sorry I don't know more beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

facing the same issue it's a change within google translate api's reply format, for me neither translate nor detect_language functions is working.